# Selecting "Enable Entitlements" for iCloud causes codesign error, even with correct distribution provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have updated and rebuilt my app with a new provision profile that was configured with "Enable for iCloud" checkbox selected in the provision portal.

Next, in XCode, for the app project, I selected the box for "Entitlements" in Targets->Summary->Entitlements as shown below to support iCloud. However, as soon as I add this, I am unable to build the application as I get the dreaded 
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

The app builds successfully with NO codesign errors and installs onto hardware with the proper provisioning profile when the "Enable Entitlements" is unchecked.  As soon as I check it, it gets the codesign error.

I also tried updating the entitlements file with ABCDEF.com.myapp  (with my real iCloud ID and app id) for the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers value.

What am I doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You mention having a provisioning profile in the question title, is this a development profile or a distribution profile? The error seems to specify that you're missing a distribution profile.

Comment: I have a distribution profile.

Comment: You also have a distribution certificate that's up to date in your keychain I presume?

Comment: Yes, I re-verified I had the dist cert and dist profile by deleting them, re-downloading them both and adding them back to the project. Same error still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Btw, I wrote a blog post with a solution which could be helpful.

You may try to copy and paste the `<dict>` of key *entitlements* from your provisioning profile to your.entitlements (a plist) file.

[iCloud Gotchas](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2011/12/icloud-gotchas.html)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I copied the <dict> data into my provisioning profile but then XCode would NOT allow me add the updated prov profile...probably because it is now "hacked".

Comment: Ok, problem solved thanks to palaniraja!  Your suggestion to edit the entitlements in the Prov prof didn't work. HOWEVER, your observation you point out in your blog points to the bug and solution. If you create a new application Id and enable iCloud then everything works fine. Enabling iCloud on existing accounts will cause the problem I hit.  SO, I created a WHOLE new App ID and made prov prof for it and Surprise! It had all the correct entitlements! So, there is a BUG with how Apple handles old app IDs (apps that existed before iCloud/iOS5) App IDs.

Comment: One last point, when using an EXISTING Apple ID, then enabling iCloud and then REGENERATING the prov profile...it does NOT solve this problem. I was forced to create a whole new APP ID to solve this.  If you create and APP ID after iCloud/iOS5 existed...you are ok.  But if you had and old APP ID (before iOS5)..you will likely hit this bug.

Comment: @MStudios I think you edited the provisioning profile. You should copy the dict from provisioning profile to entitlements file. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. It ended up being a Apple Provisioning Portal issue.

Even though I followed these steps:
1. Selected "Enable for iCloud" for the App ID
2. Created(regenerated) a new provision profile that was configured for the respective "Enable for iCloud" app
3. In XCode, for the app project, I selected the box for "Entitlements" in Targets->Summary->Entitlements as shown below to support iCloud.

The build error still persisted.  So, I looked at the Prov Prof with an editor and the entitlements were NOT in there even though I just generated a new one.

What I found was after about 1 week, surprise!, if I generated the Prov. Profile now it had the entitlements in it! So, there was a delay before the generation of the PP's would pick up the iCloud entitlements.  Also I filed this issue with Apple so they are aware of this strange delay.